# Code stop if 404 not found

Tags: c#, .net

Hi I use the code below to check 5 url but if the ex: url no 3 is 404 not found the code will stop from checking the 4th url, anyway I can do to make the code run untill the url lists finished?

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
                for (i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
                {       
                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        listBox3.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
                    }
                }
        }
        catch (WebException x)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you'll get `404` before calling `request.GetResponse`

Comment: yes I removed some of the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception could be  thrown in `request.GetResponse()` part of your application.

But anyway, in your code after exception compiler will  break out of the loop, because your try/catch is in the outside of your loop. So, change your code to:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {      
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    listBox3.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                // do whatever you want
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes. But as @I4V commented to your question, you can't get `404` exception before calling `request.GetResponse`.  Also, what is the value of the 'listBox1.Items[i].ToString()', which causes exception?

Comment: some urls, if the site is unreachable or 404 not found, maybe some other error too like forbidden status.

Answer (score 0):

Move the exception handling to within the loop. That way if there's an exception, you don't break out of the loop.